# How do I auto download file in public folder in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

I have added a text file in public folder. I am able access it on for example http://www.example.com/file.txt.

When I visit the url, it shows the text file in the browser itself but my requirement is it should download the file rather than reading it in browser as soon as user visit the url. I am using Next.js 10. How do I do it?

Current Behavior: Browser is reading the text file and displaying it in the webpage.

Expected Behavior: File should start downloading on visiting the url which is path to the file in public folder.

Comment: To force the file to download, try adding a `Content-Disposition` header to the server response with the value `attachment` followed by the filename -- https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#d1z39n6mcaodugmpvhfr1 -- remember to update button `<a href="/api/download?fileName=file.txt">Download file</a>`